# How to extract column_name String and data Vector from a one-column DataFrame in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I was able to extract the column of a DataFrame that I want using a regular expression, but now I want to extract from that DataFrame column a String with the column name and a Vector with the data. How can I construct `f` and `g` below? Alternate approaches also welcome.

```
julia> df = DataFrame("x (in)" => 1:3, "y (°C)" => 4:6)
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x (in)  y (°C) 
     │ Int64   Int64  
─────┼────────────────
   1 │      1       4
   2 │      2       5
   3 │      3       6

julia> y = df[:, r"y "]
3×1 DataFrame
 Row │ y (°C) 
     │ Int64  
─────┼────────
   1 │      4
   2 │      5
   3 │      6

julia> y_units = f(y)
"°C"

julia> y_data = g(y)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 4
 5
 6
```

Comment: Isolating the units can be achieved with `match` and `strip` once the column name is extracted: `units = strip(match(r"\(.*\)", column_name).match, ['(',')'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f(df) = only(names(df))
g(df) = only(eachcol(df)) # or df[!, 1] if you do not need to check that this is the  only column
```

(`only` is used to check that the data frame actually has only one column)

An alternate approach to get the column name without creating an intermediate data frame is just writing:

```
julia> names(df, r"y ")
1-element Vector{String}:
 "y (°C)"
```

to extract out the column name (you need to get the first element of this vector)